# Reading individual numbers from text file in ncurses

Tags: arrays, file, text, ncurses

I've got a text file filled with numbers with no spaces between them, with the same number of digits in each row (it's actually an ASCII image). I need to read each individual digit (0-9) into a two-dimensional array in ncurses that I will later print into a window in order to reproduce the ASCII image. "scanw" isn't working for me, but neither is getch(). How can I make this work?

Here's the relevant section of code:

```
int aboutArray[LINES][COLS];

FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
if (myFile == NULL) {
    wprintw(aboutWin, "Failure to open file");
    return(1);
}

//read file into array
for (i = 0; i < LINES; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        scanw(myFile, "%1d", &aboutArray[i][j]);
    }
}
fclose(myFile);

for (i = 0; i < LINES; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        wprintw(aboutWin, 0, 0, "%1d", aboutArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`scanw`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_scanw.3x.html) doesn't read from a [**`FILE`**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdio.h.html); it reads from a [**`WINDOW`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Datatypes).

Use [`fscanf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html).

Comment: Thank you! But alas that doesn't solve the problem. It compiles without issue, but I get a "Segmentation fault: 11" when hit that chunk of code while running the program. But it doesn't look like scanf exists in ncurses. The options appear to be scanw, wscanw, and vwscanw.

Comment: `fscanf` is in the standard C runtime, and you have it.  `scanf`, `sscanf` and `fscanf` are all different (and reading the manual pages would help).